# Wordpress site deletes the edits I made

Tags: wordpress

I would need some help with my Wordpress site.

I made a lot of change in my theme (one-page-express):

- added some plugins and edited the code as well (I only edited header.php, header-homepage.php, footer.php and style.css).

For a while everything looks okay but then after a few hours it seems to auto delete the changes I made in the editor.

Keeps the new plugins and its edits though, but all the code gets restored to default.

Anyone has any idea why is it happening and how could I fix it?

I learnt coding/Wordpress by myself so I might have missed some crucial point, I don’t know.

Thanks anyone who can help me!

Comment: Can you share plugin names which are installed by you

Answer (score 1):

First, try to desactive yours plugins one by one and check if you have something new. And be sure to have correctly crushed your old files (In you FTP manager, you can see the last date of editting a file, don't miss something ;))

Comment: It was one of my plugins. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

NEVER make changes in an existing theme if you want them to persist. Use a child theme to do so. I guess you pressed the update button (as you should). Updating a theme will remove/delete the current theme (all files) and download the latest version. This might look and feel like 'auto-delete'.

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will do a child theme.